# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyfadecolor (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyfadecolor

Tags: python

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-http-client (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-http-client

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.